# How to install Netbeans 9 on Windows simple way?

Tags: netbeans

Apache NetBeans 9.0, released on the 29th of July, 2018.

Installing 8.2 is really easy, you just go here and download the installer.

Installation of 9.0 is an enigma. The official site here Only provides either source or a Mac version.

Is there a simple way? Something like taking installer and install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This is the download page

> https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html

- Choose the link that says: `Binaries: incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip ( PGP ASC, SHA-1)`. It does not specify that it is for Windows, but it is for Windows.
- Choose any http mirrors. It is rather old school that they cannot make a proper `balance loader` or CDN to group this links into one. However they are legit links.
- now go back and press the `SHA-1` link from the line `Binaries: incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip ( PGP ASC, SHA-1)`. This guys do not trust what they are linking to. So the only way you can be sure that you have downloaded what is needed is to check the file Hash. To get a Hash of your file go to command line and run

> certutil -hashfile ~/Downloads/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip

and you will get something like that:

> SHA1 hash of C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip:
>
> e03f8bec1d56bd50287e4827282cdbbaae37812e
>
> CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.

So now you can compare your Hash with expected Hash.

- I recommend to Unzip `netbeans` folder from `.zip` it to root directoyr in `C:\` to avoid dealing with Windows `User Account Control (UAC)` technology.
- Executable for Windows 10 (64) is  `C:\netbeans\bin\netbeans64.exe`.
- Once you start it, it most likely would give you a message saying that a `java` library needs to be installed/updated. There would be a button saying `<install bla-blah-java-something>`, do not hesitate to press it.
- Now you have a dialog window with a drop down list on it. This software is not making it easy for you. You need to pick something that it needs. But don't worry the first default option with `something-java-api` is what you need. Pick it. and you are ready to go.
- `Apache NetBeans IDE 9` is working all right along side with `NetBeans IDE 8.2` and `"NetBeans IDE Dev version xxxxx". You can have all 3 of them running at the same time.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer, which will help others who read this question in the future.

Comment: Installing Netbeans 10 on Windows is the same.